# Why am I getting this fetch error with next auth?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I've been trying to use next auth to authenticate my users in my page built with Nextjs 13.4.7 but I keep getting this error with nothing to work with.
I'm working with the credentials provider as shown below, which is in '/src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts':

```js
    import NextAuth from "next-auth";
    import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
    import { loginUser } from "@/services/auth";
    
    export const authOptions = {
        providers: [
            CredentialsProvider({
                name: "Credentials",
                credentials: {
                    username: {
                        label: "Username",
                        type: "text",
                        placeholder: "jsmith",
                    },
                    password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
                },
                async authorize(credentials, req) {
                    // You need to provide your own logic here that takes the credentials
                    // submitted and returns either a object representing a user or value
                    // that is false/null if the credentials are invalid.
                    // e.g. return { id: 1, name: 'J Smith', email: 'jsmith@example.com' }
                    // You can also use the `req` object to obtain additional parameters
                    // (i.e., the request IP address)
                    const res = await fetch(
                        "http://localhost:1337/api/auth/local",
                        {
                            method: "POST",
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                identifier: credentials?.username,
                                password: credentials?.password,
                            }),
                            headers: {
                                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                            },
                        }
                    );
                    const user = await res.json();
    
                    console.log(res, " res");
    
                    // If no error and we have user data, return it
                    if (user) {
                        return user;
                    }
                    // Return null if user data could not be retrieved
                    return null;
                },
            }),
        ],
        pages: {
            signIn: "/login",
        },
    };
    
    const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
    
    export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

And whenever I hit the login button I get redirected to my login form, which works fine, but after I fill the form and press de login button again, I get redirected to an error page, nothing on the console so I really don't know what the problem is. Only clue I have is that in the path, it says it has something to do with fetching
[image: Error page]